# Add image in header using html-pdf node module

Tags: node.js, npm, pdf-generation

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert the html to PDF.The conversions are really good.But the problem is to add header and footer in the PDF pages.In the options if i add the header text i got the result what i expected.

```
//Options

    var options = {
    "header": {
        "height": "45mm",
        "contents": "<div style='text-align: center;'>Author: Marc Bachmann</div>" // If i add image in content it wont work
    // sample i tried 
      },
      "footer": {
        "height": "28mm",
        "contents": "<span style='color: #444;'>{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>"
      }
    }
// Tried this in contents <img src="image path" />
    var result = <div class="container"> HTML CONTENT</div>';

        pdf.create(result, options).toFile(fileName + ".pdf", function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        callback();
        }
```

Then if i add the image tag in the header(contents) option i didn't get the image in the generated PDF. Can you please give me a solution for this thanks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? The selected answer doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to add the image in options header.
1.Load the image in html body with "display:none" style.
2.Then add the image in the options header
By doing this the image is cached and can attach the image in header.

```
    var options = {
    "format": 'Letter',
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "header": {
    "contents": "<img src='image path' />",
        "height": "30mm"
  },
  "footer": {
    "contents": footer
  }
}
pdf.create("<div style='display:none'><img src='image path' /></div>", options).toFile("sample.pdf", function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                callback();
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Refering to [this issue](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/44) on the github, you can't put your image directly in `options.header`, you have to put it in the body inside a `<div id="pageHeader"></div>`:

```
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var path = require('path');

// this is very important, you have to put file:// before your path
// and normalize the resulting path
var imgSrc = 'file://' + __dirname + '/350x120.png';
imgSrc = path.normalize(imgSrc);
// or var imgSrc = path.join('file://', __dirname, '/350x120.png');

// Options
var options = {
    "header": {
      "height": "45mm",
      "contents": ""
    },
    "footer": {
      "height": "28mm",
      "contents": "<span style='color: #444;'>{{page}}</span>/<span>{{pages}}</span>"
    }
  }
// put your entire header here and the content of the page outside the <div id="pageHeader"></div>
var result = "<div id='pageHeader'><img src='" + imgSrc + "' /><div style='text-align: center;'>Author: Marc Bachmann</div></div>";
result += "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>";
var fileName = __dirname + '/test.pdf';
pdf.create(result, options).toFile(fileName, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

With this code, I get this pdf:

[image: generated pdf]

Comment: Thanks for your reply...
Here you are created the html and pass it to the package.But i need to set the image from options header (So that it will replicate all the generated pdfs).So is it possible to do that set image from options header itself ?

Comment: Auto-quoting myself: *you can't put your image directly in options.header*. You can store the `<div id="pageHeader"></div>` in a variable and append it to the body of all your pdf.

Comment: So we should have the image in the html itself for every page ?.But still the text can be repeated in the options header.

Comment: Thanks for your help . ShanShan :)

Comment: If i am include  id='pageHeader' image is not visible otherwise its showing

Answer (score 2):

For me helped using full file path.
If using short path, the image becomes hidden.

Example:

```
<body>
<div id="pageHeader" class="header">
    <div>
        <img src="file:///C://Users//ostrovskii//Documents//2020-06-20_18-20-33_531//attachments//logo.JPG" alt="Агентство" class="render" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple and easy way to do it and you can put your image source path into your HTML.

like this

```
<div class="img">
            <img src="file:///C:/Users/mdjac/Desktop/NCC/public/img/showcase-1.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" alt="">
        </div>
```

This will work successfully to load the images and also CSS I think so.
Hopefully, this is helpful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Created a simple [NPM module](https://github.com/Kaisle/add-html-to-pdf) for this purpose that can add arbitrary HTML and CSS to an existing PDF.

```
const pdf = require('add-html-to-pdf');

var options = {
  input: 'sample.pdf',
  output: 'done.pdf',
  html: "<div style='text-align: center;'>Author: Marc Bachmann</div>",
}

pdf.insertHTMLInPDF(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will be helpful for someone.

Shanoor answer is correct and code example he provided works well if you don't set "base" property for options.

So remove "base" property and make path full.

One more way to get the path to the image. This snippet

```js
var projectRoot = process.cwd();
projectRoot = projectRoot.replace(/\\/g,'/');
var imgBase = 'file:///' + projectRoot + 'path to the image';
```

Will return something like this file:///C:/project folder/path to the image/img1.jpg

Comment: If i am include id='pageHeader' image is not visible otherwise its showing

Answer (score 0):

SIMPLE PUT THAT IMAGE STATIC INTO YR HTML FILE LIKE THIS THEN CALL IT INTO API.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
       <img src="YOUR IMAGE PATH"/>
    </div>

    <h1>ABC</h1>
    <ul>
      
      <li>Name: ABC </li>
      <li>Age: ABC </li>
      
      <br />
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To my experience, it works well with image URLs. I've tried using local images but it didn't work until I hosted all my assets online and then, it worked.