# image not show in header node-html-pdf

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf) to convert the html to PDF . But I cant add image in header . Here is my code :

nodejs :

```
const options = {
    "format": "A4",
    "base": req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') ,
};

pdf.create(fs.readFileSync(outHtml, 'utf8'), options).toFile(outPdf, function (err) {
    ... 
})
```

html:

```
<div id="pageHeader-first">
    <img src="img_path">
</div>
<div id="pageHeader"></div>
```

Where is my wrong ? Please help me

**EDIT**
I tried this code but still not working :

```
var assetPath = path.join(__dirname,'../public/')
            assetPath = assetPath.replace(new RegExp(/\\/g),'/');
            const options = {
                "format": "A4",
                base: "file://"+assetPath,
                header:{
                  height:"33mm"
                }
            };
```

html : `<img src="images/logo.jpg" style="width:100%" alt=""/>`

Comment: Have you checked the image url works fine

Comment: @iambatman yes , I'm using `https://mydomain/images/logo` in url of img . It only work when I change src of img to `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335698/add-image-in-header-using-html-pdf-node-module

Comment: thank you but it not work too @iambatman

Comment: I think its the issue with the absolute path  check this https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/44

Comment: but `https://mydoamin/images/logo` is absolute path. Isn't it ?

Comment: Try to load an with absolute path with filesystem  
 eg :`file:///home/app/files/image.png`

Comment: I'm edited my answer . And it still not working

Comment: Try that path in html page

Comment: yes , I tried it and not work too . But event it work , i thought it cant work in live server

Comment: May be its a protocol issue

Comment: I'm not sure about it , it only working when i'm using image url of google